# Why does print statements sometimes require indents while in some cases indenting print ruins the code?

Tags: python, loops, printing

So for example

```
cast = ["Barney Stinson", "Robin Scherbatsky", "Ted Mosby", "Lily Aldrin", "Marshall Eriksen"]
heights = [72, 68, 72, 66, 76]

//loop

for i, name in enumerate(cast):
    cast[i] = name + " " + str(heights[i])


print(cast)
```

If I indent the code to include it in the for loop, the print statement will return multiple copies of my output, and in a completely chaotic order. However when I instead use the print statement without an indent, everything works out fine as I return names and heights in order. Obviously the loop is the problem, but it's not the first time I've encountered this, and i'd appreciate a full in-depth explanation. Thnx!

Comment: Sounds like you need a tutorial! This isn't even executable code.

Comment: Are you trying to change the original list (so that it will contain "Barney Stinson 72" etc) or just return a list of names and heights?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this "completely chaotic order". The elements are changed from left to right, as expected...

Comment: If printing in the loop, it probably should be `print(cast[i])`

Comment: Please show us an output of the chaotic order you are talking about. After running the script I the list being printed in the same order 5 times with a number appended to the name corresponding to the index in question.

Comment: @Aran-Fey strangely enough for me when I do indent the print statement it doesn't do that.

Comment: @ChrisCharley Ah I see now. Thnx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whereas languages like C, Go, Java, etc. use braces (`{}`) do delimit blocks of code, Python uses indentation.

So this code

```
for i, name in enumerate(cast):
    cast[i] = name + " " + str(heights[i])
print(cast)
```

will first iterate over `cast` and reassign its elements (the indented block), before moving on to the next statement, in this case `print`.

This code on the other hand

```
for i, name in enumerate(cast):
    cast[i] = name + " " + str(heights[i])
    print(cast)
```

will print the entire `cast` out for each iteration of the `for` loop.

Indentation is a part of Python's core design.